# Program Wipe with I2C on 2 Due's

Tags: arduino, i2c

I have an interesting issue that could or could not be true for the Due only. I do not have the resources to test I2C on 2 Arduino ATMegas. Here is the issue:

I have two Due's: The master has an Ethernet shield that will be used later; is used now for easily differentiate between master and slave. I2C is working, however the setup is: 1 12V battery connected to the Due's DC "round" input connected to the master: 3.3V and GND are tied together between the two boards: 1 USB cable for uploading sketches.

When I unplug the USB from the master to upload a sketch on the slave, both boards remain on during the USB unplugged phase -- due to the 12 DC.
The sketch is uploaded and the USB stay on the slave side for serial monitoring.

THE ISSUE: When the 12V battery is not corrected to the master; during the USB unplugged phase, both boards are off. Upon uploading the same sketch to the slave, the serial monitor shows that no information is received by the slave.

I assume that I2C setup and uploading a sketch are conflicting. How can I resolve this issue, so I don't need power to the Dues all the time. Here is the code that is working with the 12V battery supply.

```
/**************************************************************************************************
  MASTER
****************************************************************************************************/
#include <Wire.h>

byte ISend[4];

void setup()
{
   Wire1.begin(); // join i2c bus (address optional for master)
   intToByteA((unsigned long)72992);
}

void loop()
{ 
   Wire1.beginTransmission(4); // transmit to device #4
   for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
   {
      Wire1.write(ISend[i]);
   } 
   Wire1.endTransmission();
   delay(500); 
}

void intToByteA(unsigned long num)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
   {
      ISend[i] = (byte)((num >> (8 * i)) & 0xFF);
   }
}

/*********************************************************************************************/


/************************************************************************************************
 SLAVE
*************************************************************************************************/
#include <Wire.h>

byte IReceive[4];

void setup()
{
  Wire1.begin(4);                // join i2c bus with address #4
  Wire1.onReceive(receiveEvent); // register event
  Serial.begin(9600);           // start serial for output
}

void loop()
{
  delay(223);
}

// function that executes whenever data is received from master
// this function is registered as an event, see setup()
void receiveEvent(int howMany)
{
  unsigned long test = 11;
  for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  {
     IReceive[i] = Wire1.read();
  } 
  test = byteAToInt();
  Serial.println(test);
}

unsigned long byteAToInt()
{
  unsigned long temp = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  {
     temp += (((unsigned long)IReceive[i]) << (8 * i));
  }
  return temp; 
}
```